# Calling stored procedure from nodejs return error

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I'm studying NodeJS with expressjs and so far, so good, but I have this little issue: calling a stored procedure from Workbench everything runs OK, but same sentence (copy/paste) within express shows error from MySQL engine.

```
{
    "desc_status": {
        "code": "ER_BAD_NULL_ERROR",
        "errno": 1048,
        "sqlMessage": "Column 'id_color' cannot be null",
        "sqlState": "23000",
        "index": 0,
        "sql": "CALL pinturas.add_inventory('101', '3');"
    },
    "code_status": 409
}
```

Here's my NodeJS call:

```
let sql = "CALL pinturas.add_inventory(101, 3);";
conn.query(sql, true, (err, filas) => {
    if(err){
        //next(err);
        res.status(409).json({
            desc_status: err,
            code_status: 409,
        });
        return;
    }
    (...)
});
```

Call from Workbench

```
CALL `pinturas`.`add_inventory`('101', '3');
```

and finally, stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `add_inventory`(
    IN _id_color INT(11), 
    IN _cant INT(11)
)
BEGIN
    set @numRows = (select count(*) from stock_colores where id_pintura = 1 and id_color = @_id_color);
    if @numRows > 0 then
        set @oldCant = (select cant from stock_colores where id_pintura = 1 and id_color = @_id_color);
        set @_stock_id = (select stock_id from stock_colores where id_pintura = 1 and id_color = @_id_color);
        update stock_colores set cant = (_cant + @oldCant) where stock_id = @_stock_id;
    else
        insert into stock_colores (id_pintura, id_color, cant) values (1, @_id_color, _cant);
    end if;
END
```

I appreciate any guidance. Cheers.

Comment: Which MySQL package are you using in your express app?

Comment: Hi. I'm using **mysql** and **express-myconnection**. But actually I've already solved my issue. The problem was on my Stored Procedure script. I'm publishing my solution in a few minutes... Thanks for your interest (Y) cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So guys, after a few checks and attempts, I managed to solve my problem, that actually was pretty simple and all entirely in my Stored Procedure script. I was calling parameters with @ but actually those are for variables declared within the code, not input parameters.

Here's my updated code.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `add_inventory`(
    IN _id_pintura INT(2), 
    IN _id_color INT(2), 
    IN _cant INT(2)
)
BEGIN
    set @numRows = (select count(*) from stock_colores where id_pintura = _id_pintura and id_color = _id_color);
    if @numRows > 0 then
        set @oldCant = (select cant from stock_colores where id_pintura = _id_pintura and id_color = _id_color);
        set @_stock_id = (select stock_id from stock_colores where id_pintura = _id_pintura and id_color = _id_color);
        update stock_colores set cant = (_cant + @oldCant) where stock_id = @_stock_id;
    else
        insert into stock_colores (id_pintura, id_color, cant) values (_id_pintura, _id_color, _cant);
    end if;
END
```